# Basic question about introducing sets and sets in a model

Tags: elementary-set-theory, model-theory, first-order-logic

Suppose I have two elements, $a$ and $b$. Suppose now that I want to say (using some appropriate first order language endowed with the membership symbol):

1. there is a set $B = \{a, b\}$,
2. the element $a$ is a member of the set $B$.

What does a very simple model of that look like? Does the structure need to contain three items: $a$, $b$, and $B$, plus the membership relation $\{(a, B), (b, B)\}$?

Or is there really just two items in the structure, namely $a$ and $b$, and then $B$ is somehow constructed using just logical operators or something? (If so, how is it constructed?)

Perhaps I just need a simple example of how I would use an appropriate first order language to write the sentences (1) and (2) above and how I would construct a model of them.

Comment: I think models usually have symbols which are used and axioms. Typically a set is associated. I think it depends too cause you can get model theory stuff which is maybe less formal but used for things like universal algebra (algebras, grpups, etc). Then you get more formal and general models about general theories like ZFC, maybe peanino(however spelled) arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects that exist need to be an actual object in your model, so $a$ and $b$ and $B$ need to correspond to objects in your model.

However, you did not have rules stating that $a$, $b$, and $B$ are distinct, so they might as well be the same object.

Also, you did not have rules stating that other objects don't exist, so your model might have extra elements.

Comment: Ah, that's helpful. Talk about "constructing" sets got me confused.

Good point about stipulating that the objects are distinct: a and b could be the same object if I don't stipulate otherwise, and then the set {a, b} would really just be a singleton.